# After reloaddata in tableview stay in the same position

Tags: ios, label, tableview

The user will click a button in one of the cell and the table will reload the data.
I would like to let the user stay in the same position after the reload.
My table contain many section and each section has two row. 
Each of them may have different height.

I have tried some of the methods provided by others but its doesn't work.

```
CGPoint offset = tableView.contentOffset;
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView setContentOffset:offset];
```

Is it related to my table that each row in each section has different heigt?

I have also check that the offset is correct after the table is reloaded.
But the appearance is wrong.

I found that the view of the table is not change after the setting the offset

Comment: You are keeping contentOffset of the 'tableView' but reloading 'messageTable' . This may be the problem.

Comment: edited   its the same

Comment: Have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: NO but i caculating it at the row in cell and pass the the height